# Java : How to pass data from one class to another using interface?

Tags: java, interface, overriding

We know java can `extends` with only one class. In this case I want to do the bellow work using `interface`.

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass extends Mango {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainActivity over = new MainActivity();
        over.run();
    }

    public void run(){
        one();
    }

    @Override
    public void two(String s){
        System.out.println("result : "+s);
    }
}
```

**Mango.java**

```
public class Mango {
    public void one(){
        System.out.println("mango one");
        two("mango two");
    }
    public void two(String s){}
}
```

**Output :**

```
mango one
result : mango two
```

**The Problem :**

In this case I got **result : mango two** by *extending* **MainClass** with **Mango**. But in my project the **MainClass** already *extends* with another class. That's why I want to use an **interface** that I will *implements* with **MainClass** for *Override* method `two()` of **Mango** class

> as if I can receive data from Mango class

How can I do that?

Comment: Is MainActivity mistake for MainClass ? Also clarify because it's kind of unclear : explain the real problem you have, not the problem you think you have for this particulary stuff

Comment: Passing value is very unclear, the real purpose maybe be more specific : like set an attribute, compute a value, but only "pass" has no real goal

Comment: Without knowing the context I would say , use composition(ie.Mango will be a field of the mainclass) or  change to inheritance chain to: Mainclass->Mango->AnotherClass (But: only do that if Mainclass IS A Mango and Mango IS A anotherClass)

Comment: I want to call method `one()` from MainClass class. The `one()` class will do some activity and pass result on method `two()`.
Now I want to override method `two()` for get and process result of method `one()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by using `Interface`, in jdk8 you can declare `default` and `static` methods and not mandatory to override in child class

```
public interface MongoSample {

default void one(){
    System.out.println("mango one");
    two("mango two");
}
default void two(String s){}

}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class MainClass implements MongoSample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainClass over = new MainClass();
    over.run();
}

public void run(){
    one();
}
@Override
public void two(String s){
    System.out.println("result : "+s);
}

}
```

output:

```
mango one
result : mango two
```

Comment: Wow! you are great! Thank you.

Comment: what about if i want to send data from dialog class when button is pressed to Main Activity using interface